# R semisimple ring implies R direct sum of finite number of minimal left ideals.

Tags: ring-theory, modules

I'm working through a proof of this statement which goes roughly as follows:

"The simple submodules of $R$  (as a module over $R$) are exactly the minimal left ideals of $R$. So (from earlier theorem) $R = \bigoplus_{i \in I} S_i$ where each $S_i$ is a minimal left ideal...''

Then comes the part that I don't understand:

"**...In particular the element $1 \in R$ can be written as a finite sum,
\begin{eqnarray*}
  1  = x_{i_1} + \dots + x_{i_n}
\end{eqnarray*}
where $x_{i_j} \in S_{i_j}$.** It then follows by multiplication of $r = r \cdot 1$...''

I don't see why $1$ can be written as this finite sum?

Comment: Because *everything* in $R$ can be written as such a sum if $R = \bigoplus_{i \in I} S_i$; look at the definition of direct sum.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not a special property of the element $1$. In fact, every element $x\in R = \bigoplus_{i \in I} S_i$ can be written as a finite sum
\begin{eqnarray*}
  x  = x_{i_1} + \dots + x_{i_n}
\end{eqnarray*}
where $x_{i_j} \in S_{i_j}$ and $i_j\in I$.

This is a direct consequence of the [definition of direct sums of rings](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_sum#Direct_sum_of_rings).

Comment: I’d go ahead and link; it’ll make the answer more useful in the future.

Comment: Note that quickly pressing "esc" before the wikipedia page loads allows you to remain on the page (though some of the images don't appear)

Comment: of dear! Of course. Thank you!